# Modal não redirecionar ao executar Post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-3

Possuo uma `View` onde abro um `Modal` para cadastrar um novo dado. Está funcionando perfeitamente. O problema, é que ao cadastrar utilizando este `Modal`, ele me redireciona para a página pré definida no c`Controller`. Porém, eu necessito apenas que o `Modal` feche, ao clicar em `Salvar`.

Em meu `Controller`, eu possuo o seguinte método para salvar:

```
public ActionResult Adicionar()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Adicionar(ConstrutoraViewModel construtoraViewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _construtoraAppService.Adicionar(construtoraViewModel);
              //Faço o redirecionamento aqui, pois utilizo este método fora do modal também.
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(construtoraViewModel);
        }
```

No próprio `Controller` eu faço o redirecionamento. Porém, necessito que ele continue, pois utilizo ele para realizar a ação `Modal` também.

A minha `View` de cadastro está desta forma:

```
@model Sisco.Application.ViewModels.ConstrutoraViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Adicionar Construtora";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Adicionar", "Construtora"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <br /><br />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome, new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CNPJ, new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CNPJ, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CNPJ, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                @Html.Label("DDD", new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DDD, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DDD, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                </div>
                @Html.Label("Telefone", new {@class = "control-label col-md-2", style = "width: 100px"})
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telefone, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control", style = "width: 81%"}})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Telefone, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                </div>
                <div class="3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <hr />


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                @Html.Label("CEP", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Endereco.CEP, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "cepConstrutora" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Endereco.CEP, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Endereco.Bairro, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Endereco.Bairro, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "bairroConstrutora" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Endereco.Bairro, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                @Html.Label("Logradouro", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Endereco.Logradouro, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "enderecoConstrutora" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Endereco.Logradouro, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                @Html.Label("Nº", new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Endereco.Numero, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Endereco.Numero, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="5"></div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Endereco.Complemento, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Endereco.Complemento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Endereco.Complemento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                @Html.Label("Estado", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Endereco.Estado, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "estadoConstrutora" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Endereco.Estado, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                @Html.Label("Cidade", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Endereco.Cidade, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "cidadeConstrutora" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Endereco.Cidade, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="5"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Construtora")" cla class="btn btn-danger">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" />
                    Cancelar
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

E estou chamando o `Modal` com a `View` desta forma:

```
    <div class="col-md-4" align="left">
                    @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Adicionar", "Construtora", new { href = "#myModal", data_toggle = "modal",
                                                                            @class = "btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign",
                                                                            @id = "btnAddConstrutora",
                                                                            @title="Adicionar Nova Construtora"
               })


<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Cadastrar Nova Construtora</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Construtora/Adicionar.cshtml", new ConstrutoraViewModel());
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Pensei em criar um novo método semelhante, e não retirar o redirecionamento. Porém isso seria um retrabalho, e mesmo assim, não creio que essa seja a melhor opção.

**Resumo do problema:** Necessito que ao executar o `Post` da `Action` em meu `Modal`, o mesmo não atualize a página. Que simplesmente feche o `Modal`.

- Estou utilizando a Versão 3.3.4 do `Bootstrap`

Comment: Acho que você deveria ter colocado o Ajax aqui. Como não tem código JavaScript, não temos como saber como a invocação da modal é executada.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez não entendi muito bem seu comentário. Porém, a invocação do Modal está toda no código. Eu não estou utilizando JavaScript para chamar o modal. O actionLink que estava chamando o mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, a melhor solução que achei até o momento foi esta:

Eu criei uma requisição `Ajax`, onde chamo o `Modal` por ela, assim:

```
  <div class="col-md-4" align="left">
                            @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Adicionar", "Construtora", null, new
                    {
                        id = "btnAddConstrutora",
                        @class = "btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign",
                        @title = "Adicionar Nova Construtora"
                    })
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="dialogDiv" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div id="dialogContent"></div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        //Optional: turn the chache off
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

        $('#btnAddConstrutora').click(function () {
            $('#dialogContent').load(this.href, function () {
                $('#dialogDiv').modal({
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: true
                }, 'show');
                bindForm(this);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });

    function bindForm(dialog) {
        $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        $('#dialogDiv').modal('hide');
                        // Refresh:
                        // location.reload();
                    } else {
                        $('#dialogContent').html(result);
                        bindForm();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    }

</script>
```

E em meu `Controller` eu simplesmente verifico se a requisição esta vindo de `Ajax` ou não.
Caso esteja, eu sei que é do meu `Modal` e faço outro tratamento para ele. No caso, não estou dando o `Redirect`. Ficando assim:

```
 public ActionResult Adicionar()
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return View("_AdicionarModalPredio");
            }
            return View();
        }
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Adicionar(ConstrutoraViewModel construtoraViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _construtoraAppService.Adicionar(construtoraViewModel);

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return Json(new { success = true });
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(construtoraViewModel);
    }
```

Dessa forma, eu chamo uma `PartialView` ao invés da `View`, apenas para tratar melhor o `Layout`.

Comment: Se alguém possuir uma resposta melhor, ficarei feliz em conhecer.

Answer (score 1):

Uma sugestão é voce criar um método `void` que execute o `adicionar`, assim ele não fará o redirecionamento após inserir, e para não haver duplicidade de código o método que redireciona pode chamar este método `void` e em seguida fazer o direcionamento.